# Google Apps Script Find function caller id

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that dynamically generates buttons and assigns for each a ClickHandler which in turn calls a function.
My problem is that because every button calls the same function I can't find a way to indentify which of them actually made the call. Here is a code sample:

```
var handler = app.createServerHandler("buttonAction");
for (i=1,...) {
  app.createButton(...).setId(i).addClickHandler(handler);
}
function buttonAction() {
  //How do I know what button made the call?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use the e.parameter.source value to determine the ID of the element that triggered the serverHandler to be called.

Here's an example:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("buttonAction");

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    app.add(app.createButton('button'+i).setId(i).addClickHandler(handler));
  }
  return app;
}


function buttonAction(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.source);    
}
```

e.parameter.source will contain the ID of the element, which you could then use to call app.getElementById(e.parameter.source) ...

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple handlers, each for one button:

```
for (i=1,...) {
  var handler = app.createServerHandler("buttonAction" + i);
  app.createButton(...).setId(i).addClickHandler(handler);
}

function buttonAction1() {
  // code to handle button 1
}

function buttonAction2() {
  // code to handle button 2
}

function buttonAction...
```

I wouldn't recommend of having these sort of "anonymous" action handlers though, as you might be having troubles later in remembering which actionX does what.

(e.g. have a different approach, w/o a loop, or prepare a dictionary-like/array object of meaningful handler names before that loop.)

OTOH, you could use event object argument provided to your callback function:

```
function buttonAction(event) {
  // use event object here to identify where this event came from
}
```

The thing is the above `event` object properties depends on where your callback is being called from. For instance, if it were a submit button where you had a Form, then you could access parameters submitted by that from like so: `event.parameter.myParamName`. See [code sample here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces#UIUpdate).

So, if you have a variable number of buttons, you could use a hidden element + the button:

```
for (i=1,...) {
  var hiddenAction = app.createHidden("action", "action"+i);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler("buttonAction");
  handler.addCallbackElement(hiddenAction);

  var btn = app.createButton("Button text", handler);

  // you'll need to add both btn and hidden field
  // to the UI
  app.add(hiddenAction);
  app.add(btn);
}
```

Then, your `buttonAction` might look like this:

```
function buttonAction(e) {
  var action = e.parameter.action;
  // do something based on action value here
  // which will be one of "action1", "action2", ...
}
```

The above is a copy & paste from [Hidden class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_hidden) sample.

The above might not work out of the box, but you get the idea: create a hidden element that holds the info you need in your callback, and attach that hidden to your server handler. You could even create multiple hidden elements or a Form panel.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your answer. I can't create multiple functions as the number of buttons is variable. I thought about using the parameters, but if you pass an array of buttons as a callback element to the handler, how do you go about identifying which one was pressed in the first place? Also I've tried the arguments.callee.caller method but it doesn't return the button object and also I've heard it has been deprecated.

Comment: I see. I added a sample that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It works using Tag.

EG

#### SETUP

```
var button = addButton(app
                    ,panel
                    ,"buttonActiveTrelloProjects_" + i.toString()
                    ,appVars.buttonWidth() + "px"
                    ,appVars.level2ButtonHeight().toString() + "px"
                    ,false
                    ,false
                    ,"Trello"
                    ,"buttonActiveTrelloProjectsHandler"
                       ,(appVars.buttonLhsGap() * buttonCntr) + (appVars.buttonWidth() * (buttonCntr - 1 )   + 9)
                    ,(appVars.level2ButtonTopGap() * 34) 
                    ,3
                    ,"button");
      button.setTag(projectName );
```

#### USE

```
function buttonActiveProjectsChartHandler_1(button){

...

buttonTag        = getButtonTag(button);
chartType        = buttonTag.split(";")[1];
activeProject    = buttonTag.split(";")[0]; 

...



}

function getButtonTag(button){
var jsonButton = JSON.stringify(button);
  var source = button.parameter.source;
  var tagPtr = source + "_tag";
  return button.parameter[tagPtr];
}
```