# Getting an ID or Tag of Pressed Button in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to use Google AppsScripts to get the value of a Button ID or TAG generated during a for{} and placed in a FlexTable.

I have to use a FlexTable because the size of the table will vary depending upon the data in the spreadsheet that I am reading.

When a user clicks on the edit button, I need to be able to ascertain the row of the FlexTable.  To do so, I have tried both adding the row number to the button as a Tag as well as an ID and tried to grab the value of the clicked element in the next function to no avail.  I do not get an error, but there is an empty variable in the second function.

Is there a way to get the value of the ID or Tag of a button pressed in Google AppScripts?

Here are the relevant portions of my code.

```
function projectList(e){
  //spreadsheet and panel stuffs

  var projectsPanel = app.createFlexTable().setId("projectsList"); 
  var team = e.parameter.team.toString();

  var editProjectsHandler = app.createServerHandler("projectDetails");


  for (var i=1;i<topManSSData.length;i++){
    //for loop conditions to look up relevant data.

    var projectName = datafromSpreadsheet

    var editButton = app.createButton("edit").setId("editButton").addClickHandler(editProjectsHandler).setTag(i); 

    projectsPanel.setWidget(row,0,app.createHTML(projectName)).setWidget(row,1, editButton)
}                   

return app;   
}
```

//the purpose of this second function is to grab the ID or TAG of the button pressed so that I can then look up the data that corresponds with the row in the FlexTable using an array function.

```
function projectDetails(editbutton){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var buttons = app.getElementById("editButton")
  var buttonid = buttons.getTag();               //here is where I am having prolems getting a value.  I get an empty value.

//etc.
return app;    
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the answer referenced in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105526/google-apps-script-find-function-caller-id?rq=1), the ID of the handler trigger source is included in the `e.parameter` properties.

You can easily check that using the Logger like below :

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
```

If each button has its own ID you will get this ID with `e.parameter.source` as a string in the handler function.  You don't need to create separate handlers on each button.

in your code sample use like this :

```
for (var i=1;i<topManSSData.length;i++){
    //for loop conditions to look up relevant data.
    var projectName = datafromSpreadsheet
    var editButton = app.createButton("edit").setId("editButton"+i).addClickHandler(editProjectsHandler); 
    projectsPanel.setWidget(row,0,app.createHTML(projectName)).setWidget(row,1, editButton)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this post might be the same issue you have:

[Google Apps Script Find function caller id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105526/google-apps-script-find-function-caller-id?rq=1)

Maybe you could create a separate click handler for every button:

```
var editButton = app.createButton("edit"+ i).setId("editButton"+i).addClickHandler(editProjectsHandler+i).setTag(i);
```

Then every button would have it's own handler. That way, whatever handler was triggered would be directly correlated to the button.

With HTML you could use `this.id` as the argument in the function call, but I don't know if that is possible with the UI Service.

Comment: Thanks Sandy Good.  The answer was in your link.  You can get the id of the element that started a function with e.parameter.source; Simple enough!